# Pattern Matching in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching

One of the column in my input dataset has values like below :
"`Super Singers 10/23 05:30A T (30) on Star (maa)`"

I need to get the play duration which is in brackets.
For the above value , the play duration is 30

I need this using scala in spark. Is there any pattern matching for this kind of strings ?

Comment: Can you please update the ques with the code you have tried so far

Comment: Please post [MCVE], otherwise it would be hard for us to help.

Comment: Example :  val input = "Super Singers 10/23 05:30A T (30) on Star (maa)"    We  need to parse this and get the value 30 from it

Comment: You're looking for regular expression

Comment: Complementing @KrzysztofAtłasik comment, take a look to [this](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> val value = "Super Singers 10/23 05:30A T (30) on Star (maa)"
value: String = Super Singers 10/23 05:30A T (30) on Star (maa)

scala> val pat = """\([0-9]+\)""".r
pat: scala.util.matching.Regex = \([0-9]+\)

scala> pat.findFirstIn(value).mkString.replaceAll("""\(""","").replaceAll("""\)""","")
res9: String = 30
```

Comment: @vidyan could you please accept the answer if this answered your question?